# Pyspark Py4j IllegalArgumentException with spark.createDataFrame and pyspark.ml.clustering

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, py4j

Let me disclose the full background of my problem first, I'll have a simplified MWE that recreates the same issue at the bottom. Feel free to skip me rambling about my setup and go straight to the last section.

**The Actors in my Original Problem:**

1. A spark dataframe `data` read from Amazon S3, with a column `scaled_features` that ultimately is the result of a `VectorAssembler` operation followed by a `MinMaxScaler`.
2. A spark dataframe column `pca_features` that results from the above df column after a PCA like so:

```py
mat = RowMatrix(data.select('scaled_features').rdd.map(list))
pc = mat.computePrincipalComponents(2)
projected = mat.multiply(pc).rows.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF().withColumnRenamed('_1', 'pca_features')
```

3. Two instances of `BisectingKMeans` fitting to both instances of features in the abovementioned data frames like so:

```py
kmeans_scaled = BisectingKMeans(featuresCol='scaled_features').setK(4).setSeed(1)
model1 = kmeans_scaled.fit(data)

kmeans_pca = BisectingKMeans(featuresCol='pca_features').setK(4).setSeed(1)
model2 = kmeans_pca.fit(projected)
```

**The Issue:**

While `BisectingKMeans` fits to `scaled_features` from my first df without issues, when attempting a fit to the projected features, it errors out with the following

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1413.fit.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type equal to one of the following types:
[struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>, array<double>, array<float>]
but was actually of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.
```

As you can see, Py4J complains that I'm passing data in a certain struct type that happens to be the first type specified in the list of allowed types.

**Additional Debug Info:**

My Spark is running version 2.4.0

Checking the dtypes yields: `data.dtypes: [('scaled_features', 'vector')]` and `projected.dtypes: [('pca_features', 'vector')]`. The Schema is the same for both dataframes as well, printing just one for reference:

```
root
 |-- scaled_features: vector (nullable = true)
```

**Recreating the error (MWE):**

It turns out that this same error can be recreated by creating a simple data frame from some Vectors (the columns in my original dfs are of VectorType as well):

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
from pyspark.ml.clustering import BisectingKMeans

test_data = spark.createDataFrame([Row(test_features=DenseVector([43.0, 0.0, 200.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0])),
    Row(test_features=DenseVector([44.0, 0.0, 250.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])),
    Row(test_features=DenseVector([23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])),
    Row(test_features=DenseVector([25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0])),
    Row(test_features=DenseVector([19.0, 0.0, 200.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]))])

kmeans_test = BisectingKMeans(featuresCol='test_features').setK(4).setSeed(1)
model3 = kmeans_test.fit(test_data)
```

The last line results in the same error I'm facing in my original setup.

Can anyone explain this error and suggest a way to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more days of investigation, I was pointed to the (rather embarrassing) cause of the issue:

Pyspark has two machine learning libraries: `pyspark.ml` and `pyspark.mllib` and it turns out they don't go well together. Replacing `from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector` by `from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector` resolves all the issues.